# Ubuntu 18.04 No Wired connection

Tags: networking, 18.04, connection, wired

[View "lspci" output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QwfT.png) I have a Dell laptop and there isn't even an option on Ubuntu 18.04 to set wired connection there is only wifi and in a network, there is VPN written only. when I plug-in cable my laptop still runs on wifi. I have tried every way which I found on the internet to fix it but nothing helped me so far.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your ethernet device and let's see if it has a proper driver. Please open a terminal and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Next, edit your answer to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It doesn't give me anything. there is nothing like 0200

Comment: May we see all of: `lspci`?

Comment: Edited, you can view.

Comment: We see no ethernet device at all. Is there an option in the BIOS to enable or disable it? Is it possible that it's broken?